# Simple Contour Integral

Tags: contour-integration, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

I have forgotten much of the complex analysis I once knew. How do I go about using the Cauchy Integral Formula / Residue Theorem to solve this contour integral? The region is the unit circle.

$$\oint \frac{(1 + z)^4}{z^3} dz.$$

Comment: the origin is the only residue of order 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac{(1+z)^4}{z^3}=z^{-3}+4z^{-2}+6z^{-1}+4+z$$

The residue is the coefficient on the $z^{-1}$ term of the Laurent series.

Comment: Can you explain why it ends up being the $z^{-1}$ term that's important?

Comment: Sure.  Integrate $z^{-n}$ around a circle, centered at the origin.  If $n\ne 1$, the value of the integral is $0$.  If $n=1$, the value is $2\pi i$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$f^{(n)}(z_0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz$$

And $f(z)$ is analytic.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @MrYouMath Using the Cauchy Integral Formula we have$$\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{(1+z)^4}{z^3} dz =\frac{2\pi \iota [12(1+z)^2]_{z=0}}{2!}=12\pi\iota $$

Comment: The answer is not $6\pi i$.

Comment: @Dr. MV thanks, the answer is revised.